# Getting an false result while deleting an element from the middle of a doubly linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, doubly-linked-list

Code for doubly LinkedList: (Main focus on the last `else` part of the `delete_from_list` function.)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None

def create_list():
    seq = input("Enter the sequence: ").split()
    int_seq = [int(i) for i in seq]
    head = None
    tail = None
    for i in int_seq:
        if i == -1:
            break
        n = Node(i)
        if head is None:
            head = n
            tail = n
        else:                # Tail must be pointing to some node already
            tail.next = n
            n.prev = tail
            tail = n
    return head, tail 

def traverse_list_forward(head):
    if head is None:
        return -1
    curr = head
    arr = []
    while curr:
        arr.append(curr.data)
        curr = curr.next
    print(' '.join(map(str, arr)))
    return head

def traverse_list_backward(tail):
    if tail is None:
        return -1
    curr = tail
    arr = []
    while curr:
        arr.append(curr.data)
        curr = curr.prev
    print(' '.join(map(str, arr)))
    return tail

def delete_from_list(head, tail, elem):
    if head is None or tail is None:
        return -1, -1

    if head.data == elem:     # Delete first element 
        if head == tail:
            head = tail = None
            return -1, -1

        curr = head
        head = head.next
        head.prev = None
        curr = None
        return head, tail

    elif tail.data == elem:   # Delete last element
        curr = tail
        if tail == head:
            tail == None
            return -1, -1

        tail = tail.prev
        tail.next = None
        curr = None
        return head, tail

    else:                     # Delete an element in between head and tail ptrs
        curr = head
        while curr:
            if curr.data == elem:
                break
            else:
                curr = curr.next

        if not curr:
            return -1, -1

        curr.prev = curr.next.prev
        curr.next = curr.prev.next
        print(curr.prev.next.data)
        print(curr.next.prev.data)
        curr.next = curr.prev = None
        curr = None
        return head, tail
```

The delete function removes that particular Node of `elem` and returns the `head` and `tail` pointer of the updated linked_list.

On trying to run:

```
list_head, list_tail = delete_from_list(list_head, list_tail, 12)
```

with the input: `1 3 5 6 7 2 12 4 8 0 9` , I'm getting output of print statement of the last `else` part (inside the delete func) as `4 12`
Should the output for the print statement not be `2 12` as curr.next.prev is now pointing to  2??

After deletion, If I try to traverse the list now using the code:

```
list_head = traverse_list_forward(list_head)
list_tail = traverse_list_backward(list_tail)
```

I get this weird output as:

```
1 3 5 6 7 2 12
9 0 8 4 12
```

Head and tail pointers pointing to their positions correctly, but some mess has happened which shows in traverse result.

Why this line:

```
        curr.prev = curr.next.prev
        curr.next = curr.prev.next
```

is not working properly? Am I missing something here?

PS., I'm using Jupyter Notebook for the same.

Output after attempting to delete `12` for  input `1 3 5 6 7 2 12 4 8 0 9`: is given in pic.

[image]

Comment: @ggorlen the delete function just removes the first occurrence of that ```elem``` and returns the updated ```head``` and ```tail``` pointers of the list

Comment: Had pasted the code twice accidentally, have edited it now. Sorry for that. you can view now.

Comment: Please provide example code of how you call your code, with the data - the example you've provided is very extensive, but doesn't include anything to run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Grismar , first I use ```list_head, list_tail = create_list()``` to create a list of integers using the values ```12 1 3 5 6 7 2 12 4 8 0 9 12``` during the runtime. Then I use ```list_head = traverse_list_forward(list_head)``` and ```list_tail = traverse_list_backward(list_tail)``` to traverse in fwd and backwd dir. Which works fine too. On using: ```list_head, list_tail = delete_from_list(list_head, list_tail, 12)``` it works fine in deleting ```12``` from head and tail ( in fst 2 calls), but it fails to delete 12 from middle in 3rd call & my list values on traversing gives wrong value then

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the `if` block here, you return from the function, preventing any other code inside the function from running:

```
    if head.data == elem:     # Delete first element 
        if head == tail:
            head = tail = None
            return -1, -1

        curr = head
        head = head.next
        head.prev = None
        curr = None
        return head, tail
```

Since your list starts with a `12` and you are deleting `12`, it finds `12` as the `.data` of the head, removes it and then returns - not removing anything else.

Note: there's a number of statements in your code that don't do anything, like assigning values to `curr` and clearing it. You may want to clean up using a good IDE and I'd recommend stepping through your code one line at a time, instead of running it all at once. Also, instead of getting manual input on every run, why not replace the `input()` statement with a simple bit of test data in the code, so you can run and rerun more quickly?

The second problem is this:

```
        curr.prev = curr.next.prev
        curr.next = curr.prev.next
```

If you're removing `12` and your list contains this `.. - 2 - 12 - 4 - ..`, so it tries to remove `curr` `12` from between `2` and `4`, what happens is this: `curr.prev = curr.next.prev` has the `.prev` of `12` point to the `prev` of `curr.next`, which is the `prev` of `4`, which is ... `12`. So, `prev` of `12` now points to itself.

You probably wanted something like:

```
        curr.prev.next = curr.next
        curr.next.prev = curr.prev
```

Pointing `2.next` to `4` and `4.prev` to `2`.

Comment: The problem is coming for input sequence: ```1 3 5 6 7 2 12 4 8 0 9``` on trying to delete ```12``` from here.. Have just added the image. Code seems to be working fine with Deleting from head and from tail end.

Comment: I added some more explanation to solve that problem, but like I said before - you should just use a decent IDE, remove excess code and step through your code one line at a time and it'll be obvious what the problems are. That's exactly what I'm doing and it's only taking seconds to find the problems.

Comment: By the way, I'm only addressing the issues you're asking about - I think there's a bunch of stuff that needs improvement in your code, but I appreciate you're learning, so not aiming for perfection here

Comment: Agreed. I'm just a beginner in data structures and trying to understand their working. All your advice is indeed helpful. Will eliminate the redundant pieces and logic in the code and will use better IDE.

Comment: If you feel my answer answers your question, please accept it as the answer to your question. If you have further questions that are directly related feel free to ask, but if they're really different questions, you would probably do best by starting a new and more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Got the error,

Basically, those 2 suspicious lines should've been:

```
        curr.prev.next = curr.next
        curr.next.prev = curr.prev
```

instead of the lines that are in the code currently.